# Averaging across a fixed calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I am building an overview graph that gives insight into session length in connection to churn.

I am looking to build a graph depicting the average time spent in an app on a per week basis relative to the signup date of all users.

I think I am almost there. I was able to create a graph that shows exactly that except. Except I have a summed up version of all users and not an average.

If I change the row value from SUM to AVG in my graph, the problem that I am facing then is that it takes the average of all users that have been active on that day. Instead, I also want to have not active users being counted as 0, therefore, decreasing the average value. (reflecting the churn aspect of the graph)

days since signup calculation: `DATE(([event_timestamp] - [sign_up_date]) /(1000 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))`

session length per user: `{ FIXED [user_pseudo_id], [days since signup] : SUM([engagement_time_msec])}`

I expect something in the area of 17k ms as peak instead of 900M as peak (avg instead of a sum).

[my current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTCIK.png)

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: We are using the default event "user_engagement" from firebase. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en We then join 2 selects (1 selecting the first open event with all user_engagement events) to calculate the days since signup.

Comment: Instead using [days since signup calculation], consider making different calculated field of [weeks since signup]. Here is approximately what this will look like: 

    `DATEDIFF("week", [sign_up_date], [event_timestamp])`

If you want then to see an overview showing [engagement_time_msec] relative to [weeks since signup], drag [weeks since signup] to columns and AVG([engagement_time_msec]) to rows. You'll also likely want to treat [weeks since signup] as a dimension.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, depending on what you want to see, you might consider dragging [weeks since signup] to rows and `SUM([engagement_time_msec])/COUNTD([user_pseudo_id])` to columns in order to get a sense of overall weekly engagement relative to signup date.

Comment: That definitely gets us closer to our goal. The only thing that's missing is the churn element. Ideally, we have `COUNTD([user_pseudo_id])` based on all users and not just users of the day. Example: Let's assume 100 users on day one. 30 users on day two. If the total session length of all 30 users on day 2 is 300 seconds want the graph to show 300/100=30 instead of 300/30=100.

Comment: All users would be `{fixed: COUNTD([user_pseudo_id])}`.

Comment: Couldn't you keep the fixed SUM expression as-is, and simply divide it by the total number of unique users, e.g., {fixed: countd([ID])}  ?

Comment: Thanks, @tagyoureit and Jim the fourth.  That's exactly what I was looking for.